# ValueError: reached end of bitarray

Tags: python, valueerror, bitarray

I am building a compression algorithm that takes a tab-delimited file, converts each column to binary (bitarray) using huffman coding, then converts the bitarray to hexadecimal format (ba2hex). This is using the bitarray library. I am getting the error `ValueError: reached end of bitarray` at the line: `iter = str("\t".join(canonical_decode(binary, count, symbol)))` in the decode function. My code works for many lines of the file, but not all.

Any help sorting out the reason for this error would be greatly appreciated.

```
def encode(stringMap):
    with open (test_dir_path + "compressed.txt", 'w') as compressed_file:
        for key in stringMap:
            list = stringMap[key]
            # print(list)
            dict = totalHuffmanDict[key]
            s = ""
            for string in list:
                binary = dict[string]
                s += binary
            s += "\n"
            b = bitarray(s)
            b.fill()
            hex = ba2hex(b)
            compressed_file.write(hex)
            compressed_file.write("\n")

listOfLists = []
def decode(count, symbol, key):
    with open (test_dir_path + "compressed.txt", "r") as compressed_file:
        lineNum = 0
        key = int(key)
        for line in compressed_file:
            lineNum = lineNum + 1
            
            if lineNum == key:
                binary = hex2ba(line.strip())
                iter = str("\t".join(canonical_decode(binary, count, symbol)))
                list = iter.split("\t")
                list = list[0:NUM_LINES]
                listOfLists.append(list)
```

Comment: Give examples of the input lines that work and don’t work. Make a [mcve] that calls your functions and generates the error.  We should be able to copy your example *with no changes* and reproduce the error

Comment: it sounds like a problem with the input file....  please provide and example of one that `fails` as per @MarkTolonen comment above.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.